# Presta shop dont display page after add jquery

Tags: jquery, html, prestashop

I have the latest Presta Shop. When I add above code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(catapultReadCookie("catAccCookies")){//If the cookie has been set
        jQuery("#catapult-cookie-bar").hide();
        jQuery("html").css("margin-bottom","0");
    }
});
</script>
```

And delete cache from tools/smarty/compile the website don't display. I dont know why ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As prestashop is using smarty as template language, and smarty uses curly brackets style so you can't add embeded javascript to the template files.

To add javascript to template files, it should be enclosed in {literal} .... {/literal}  smarty tags. Your code should be like this:

```
{literal}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if(catapultReadCookie("catAccCookies")){//If the cookie has been set
    jQuery("#catapult-cookie-bar").hide();
    jQuery("html").css("margin-bottom","0");
}
});
</script> 

 {/literal}
```

For literal, kindly read this

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var data = catapultReadCookie("catAccCookies");
    if(data != null && data !== 'undefined'){//If the cookie has been set
        jQuery("#catapult-cookie-bar").hide();
        jQuery("html").css("margin-bottom","0");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I must add your cod between ?
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com
</script>